# discord.js if args null its not sending the error message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a command that uses 3 args, a mentioned user one, a mentioned channel one and a text arg. But every time i miss a arg, instead of showing a error message, its shows a error in the console. The code is like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'rejeitar',
  category: 'Premium',
  description: 'rejeitar alguem na org '
  ,
run: async (client, message, args, user, guild) => {

  if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "[] Gestor tickets")){
  
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    const motivo = args.slice(2).join(' ');

    const rejeitado2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .setTitle('**❱Resultado cands**')
    .setDescription('**Rejeitado**')
    .addFields(
        { name: '**❱ Rejeitado pelo Staff**', value: `${message.author.tag}` },
    { name: '**❱ Data**', value: `${message.createdAt}` },
    { name: '**❱ Motivo**', value: `${motivo}` },
        { name: '**‍❱ Membro Rejeitado**', value:`${member}`, inline: true },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Bot feito por Chain#6988' });

     ////---------------LOG EMBED-------------/////
      
     const rejeitado = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .setTitle('**❱Infelizmente não foste aceite nos TDT**')
    .setDescription('**Tenta denovo mais tarte **')
    .addFields(
        { name: '**❱Rejeitado pelo Staff **', value: `${message.author.tag}` },
        { name: '**❱Data**', value: `${message.createdAt}` },
    { name: '**❱ Motivo**', value: `${motivo}` },
        { name: '**‍❱Membro Rejeitado**', value:`${member}`, inline: true },
    )
    .setFooter({ text: 'Bot feito por Chain#6988' });
if(channel && member ){ 
channel.send({ embeds: [rejeitado] });
channel.send (`${member}`)
   client.channels.cache.get('1002892850385657866').send({ embeds: [rejeitado2] });
    client.channels.cache.get('1002892850385657866').send(`${member}`);
       message.react("✅")
    message.channel.send("Clica no ✅ para apagar o ticket!")
 }
else
message.channel.send("**ERRO**\nVerifica se podes usar o comando ou se esta correto!(.aceitar #ticket  @pessoa rejeitada motivo")


  function filter(reaction, user) {
          return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.author.id;
      }
// Increase or decrease the time based on your needs.
const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 1500000, max: 1 });

    collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {

/* Because of the way we defined our filter, there is no need to check
if the user reacted with any other emoji than the ✅ */

channel.delete();
})

// and if the user doesn't react with anything in the time limit
collector.on('end', collected => {
 if(collected.size < 1) {
  return message.channel.send("o tempo acabou, vais ter de fechar o ticket manualmente")
   
   
 }
})
}
}
}
```

The error that shows in the console:

> 

```js
/home/runner/turqia-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:428
    if (!allowEmpty && data.length === 0) throw new error(errorMessage);
                                                ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
```

And its suppost to send a error message to the channel if it has no args or is missing one.
If you guys know a fix to this, help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is not sent because you're using an `if...else` statement.
Your initial condition returns `true`, so your `else` statement will not execute.

What you can do to solve your problem, is simply checking if there are 3 arguments used:

```
if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "[] Gestor tickets")){

  // or the equivalent index of your last argument
  if(!args[2]) {
  return message.channel.send("**ERRO**\nVerifica se podes usar o comando ou se esta correto!(.aceitar #ticket  @pessoa rejeitada motivo");
  }

// rest of your code
}
```

You can also enveil your code in a `try...catch` statement, and send the message on any error. This is not the best way to do it, but it still works.